# JPA sequence generator persists incorrect value

Tags: java, oracle, jpa

I have an Oracle DB sequence that is being called by the following JPA.  The problem is that the sequence that is being returned is not the same sequence number that the database is actually using.  The JPA component is usually one less than the actual id  for the record that is inserted into the table.  For instance, when debugging JPA states that the object's Id will be 3689711 but after the record is persisted, the actual record in the table is 3689712, but it isn't always so recognizable.  Once the record is created, I need to obtain the correct ID so that I can pass it to another process, but without the correct number, the next process fails.

```
@Id
@SequenceGenerator(name="S_DRLEARNINGACTIVITYTRANSCRIPT", allocationSize=1)
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE,generator="S_DRLEARNINGACTIVITYTRANSCRIPT")
@Basic(optional = false)
@NotNull
@Column(name = "ID")
private Long id;
```

#1**
I have the following DDL for my Oracle sequence:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE  "S_DRLEARNINGACTIVITYTRANSCRIPT"  
MINVALUE 1 MAXVALUE 999999999999999999999999999 
INCREMENT BY 1 START WITH 3690531 CACHE 20 NOORDER  NOCYCLE ;
```

I know I could work around this and add a temporary value to another field and then do a look up on a temporary value to get the real value of the PK after the record is persisted, but this seems like a lot of extra DB calls for something this basic.  Any help would be appreciated.

#2**
It appears that JPA simply queries the nextVal from the sequence but has no way of locking that in to the DB prior to the actual commit.  Since it executes the sequence to determine the next value that forces the sequence to automatically generate a new nextVal.  I'm not sure that it matters, but my sequence is triggered before the record inserts into the table.  So, when JPA finally commits the record, the underlying database trigger/sequence actually generates a new sequence value meaning the original sequence number JPA claimed to have is actually overwritten by the underlying database when it calls the sequence again.  So, the only solution that seems to make sense is to modify the underlying database trigger to not generate a sequence if the column already has a value, but that seems risky.  The sequence generation within JPA seems flawed at best if you need to take advantage of the sequence number for other processes.

Comment: Anyone rand into this before?

Comment: It seems like you have a trigger generating the ID for you in the database. You shouldn't. JPA gets a sequence and assigns it to the entity, and then the trigger also generates an ID, using the next value from the sequence. If you tell JPA to generate the value, then don't let the database generate it, and vice-versa.

Comment: Thanks.  Yes, that you are correct regarding the trigger, but according to the documentation, that's why you give the JPA sequencegenerator your sequence name (and I may improperly assume that all sequences on the DB side are bound with triggers because that is what I've always done). So I guess my question should be, how can I obtain the actual sequence that is used in the DB via JPA after the commit?